# Open multiple firewall ports in CentOS7

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, port, centos-7

I need to open multiple different ports (not in ranges) on a CentOS machine.

I know how to open a port with `firewall-cmd`, but that gets bothersome for opening like 40 and more ports.

Is there a configuration file where I can define all open ports in one place? Sadly I didn't find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a service from an xml file containing all the ports you need, add a service from it and then enable it.  Create the service.xml file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <service>
  <port port="port1" protocol="proto1"/>
  <port port="port2" protocol="proto2"/>
  <port port="port3" protocol="proto3"/>
  <port port="port4" protocol="proto4"/>
 </service>
```

Add new service:

`# firewall-offline-cmd --new-service-from-file=service.xml --name=My_Service`

Reload firewall-cmd:

`# firewall-cmd --reload`

Then add your service:

`# firewall-cmd --add-service My_Service`

Answer (score 8):

You can always make a small script/one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 80 443 22 123 21 1337 31337
do
  firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=${i}/tcp
done
```

Answer (score 8):

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={80/tcp,443/tcp,9200/tcp,5601/tcp,5044/tcp}
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and how it solves the problem. … … … … … … … … … Please do‌​ not respond in comments; edit your answer to make it clearer and more complete. … … … P.S.  Why not just do `--add-port={80,443,9200,5601,5044}/tcp`?

Comment: The trick `{}` used above is called [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Comment: what a nice hack..  thanks for that

Answer (score 6):

If those open ports are in a range for example 2379-2385, you can do as follows:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=zone_name --add-port=2379-2385/tcp
```

To make it permanent add `--permanent` option at end.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a very old question, it can get really "interesting", so I thought I should answer it.

##### Every possible port in a single line

```
# simple
firewall-cmd --add-port={80,443}/tcp

# Both protocols
firewall-cmd --add-port={80,443}/{tcp,udp}

# can be a bit complex and note the nested parentheses
firewall-cmd --add-port={{80,443}/{tcp,udp},{110,995}/tcp}
```

Then have a look at what you've done :) by typing

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

##### But services are nicer

I've also experimented with `--add-services', whose names can be found in` /etc/services'. It's even nicer than using ports. Both the names and the ports are in that file, so you can list some of them:

```
grep -E 'http|imap|pop3|smtp|dns|ftp' /etc/services
```

We can open ports by entering the following: ``:

```
# readable
firewall-cmd --add-service={http,https}
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

That's it for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same yesterday and the following was handy.

**firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port={1111,2222,3333,4445}/tcp && firewall-cmd --reload**

You can include the required ports within braces {} followed by a slash / protocol.

If the ports are consecutive, you can mention them like the following.

**firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=4444-4448/tcp && firewall-cmd --reload**

---

Run the following to ensure the ports are open

**firewall-cmd --list-ports**

Answer (score 0):

The below command will accept traffic from ports 22,53 and 80 (see [source](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/3802/How-to-allow-or-block-the-port-and-IP-Address-using-Firewalld-IP-tables-and-UFW-in-Linux.html)):

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --match multiport --dports 22,53,80 -j ACCEPT
```

I prefer this variation with reload required for permanent rules only:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dport 22,53,80 -j ACCEPT && sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```